# protobuf-net repeated field as ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

When I compile this sample .proto file with protobuf-net:

```
message A
{
   repeated float values = 1;
}
```

The generated file contains class which has `List<Single>` property. Is there any way to use `ObservableCollection<Single>` property instead of `List<Single>`? Actually, the reason is: I want to use generated class directly in WPF application, but it's a bit difficult to bind this property to somewhat because I will not see any changes in this case.

May be there is some work-around for this? Because otherwise i will have to make wraps for each class which is not very convenient.

**EDIT**: I can just replace all **lists** with **observable collections** inside of batch-file, for example, but will it lead to some problems? Or it is the real solution for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the code-gen tool is hard-coded to `List<T>`. Of course, the code-gen tool is also entirely optional - so *one* option is: don't work from the code-gen tool (it will work fine with hand-drawn DTOs). If you are happy to simply do an automated replace, that is fine - it won't upset protobuf-net at all. But if you do this lots, another option is to edit the `csharp.xslt` file in the code-generator's directory. This is an xsl-transform file that generates the code from an xml representation of the model. There are (IIRC) 3 occurrences of `global::System.Collections.Generic.List` that you can change to anything you like. You can either over-write `csharp.xslt`, or copy it into a new file (and edit that), and then just specify that as the transform when calling `protogen`.